# How reload tableView after searching and deleting a data from sqlite

Tags: swift

I added a button on an UITableView to delete data in SQLite. The button works perfectly but I'm having a hard time reloading the tableview after deletion. 
I used tableview.reload() but it wouldn't reload while I'm searching. If I add two data such as "aaa" and "aaaa" and search "aa" to delete one, you can see the two data and if you delete "aaaa", it doesn't reload automatically, and if you remove "a" after that deletion, which means the left letters are "aaa". It shows up. without typing again, there would be another way to reload tableview automatically after deletion?

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomizedCell

    cell.requiredAction = { [unowned self] in

        let DB = FMDatabase(path: self.databasesPath)
        if DB.open() {
            let result : FMResultSet? = DB.executeQuery("select * from table", withArgumentsIn: [])

            self.fullData = []
            while result?.next() == true {
                if let appendedData = result?.string(forColumn: "keyword") {
                    self.fullData.append(appendedData)
                }
            }
            self.targetData = self.searching ? self.searchedArr : self.fullData

            let query = "delete from table where keyword='\(self.targetData[indexPath.row])'"
            DB.executeStatements(query)
            self.fullData = []
            let secondResult: FMResultSet? = DB.executeQuery("select * from table", withArgumentsIn: [])

            while secondResult?.next() == true {
                if let appendedData = secondResult?.string(forColumn: "keyword") {
                    self.fullData.append(appendedData)
                }
            }
            self.tableview.reloadData()
            self.targetData = self.searching ? self.searchedArr : self.fullData

        }
    }
    cell.myLableCell1.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)

    targetData = searching ? searchedArr : fullData
    cell.myLableCell1?.text = targetData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are loading data in tableview cell file....just do the out of the class....and after
create one getdata method in class and fill array

then delete row and data from sqlite...
after again call getdata.
In getdata method you need to write tableview.reload()

i hope you got....
follow instagram : styoloholic_007 and gunatitsolutions